# PHP Prevent multiple MySQL Connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect, php-include

I have a large procedural style php/mysql website, which is splitted into many different files. Within each file, i include my dbconn.php, to ensure, that a db connection is available.

It looks something likes this:

index.php

```
<?php 
   include_once ('header.php');
   include_once ('nav.php');
   include_once ('content.php');
   include_once ('sidebar.php');
   include_once ('footer.php');
?>
```

and within each of these files i call several other files via include_once. So in total i come up with about 30 different files.

Every file starts with:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dbconn.php');
```

Since i'm using include_once, dbconn.php should not be loaded more then once, but recently i get following php warning.

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1226): User 'username' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 20) in /var/www/html/dbconn.php on line 10
```

My dbconn.php looks like this:

```
<?php
   $host = "localhost";
   $user = "username";
   $pass = "password";
   $db = "dbname";

   if(!mysqli_thread_id($con)){
       $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
       mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
   }
   unset($host,$user,$pass,$db);
?>
```

So there is a double check.
If there already is an open mysql connection, the file should do basicly nothing.

What am i doing wrong?
Why do i get this php warning and how do i reduce the amount of mysql connections?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389201/max-user-connections-set-to-200-still-getting-error check out this post.. may be solved already

Comment: You could also consider the singleton pattern to handle database connections.

Comment: @DWolf: i'm struggling with scenario #3 but is there anything i can do? i have the feeling that i'm responsible for the huge amount of connections

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's not different calls from a single page that is leading to the problem. It's the fact that you have multiple OPEN connections at the moment.

Make sure you close you connections after they have served their purpose.

Also, try to avoid the kind of structure you currently have, have all the DB related stuff included in one file and then include it only once on your page.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876412/php-and-mysqli-close
they say, that mysqli_close is not necessary...

if i decide to close the connection manually... when is the right time to do it? I have the same problem as this person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389816/a-proper-way-to-open-and-close-mysqli-queries

Comment: Try using a way where you fire all your relevant queries and then close the connection in one go.

Comment: within the ~30 files i use many SELECT queries... i do not understand how i should combine then into one file...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a singleton pattern.
So i changed the mysqli prodecural code into mysqli objectoriented.

i got the pattern here:
http://www.davecomeau.net/blog/1/Single+Database+Object+in+PHP+5+Using+the+Singleton+Pattern